# What is the sum of this fraction series?

Tags: sequences-and-series

$$\frac{1}{3} + \frac{1}{5} + \frac{1}{7} + \frac{1}{9} + \frac{1}{11} .... + \frac{1}{99}?$$ Is there a way to do without calculation? I would appreciate an answer that gives an easy way to find this sum.

Comment: In Mathematica we trust:
$$\frac{2110974836662028215585538611301887321889}
{1089380862964257455695840764614254743075}.$$ I don't think there is a useful exact closed formula for these sums. E.g. nothing that could be proved by induction.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Define $$H_k=\frac{1}{1}+\frac{1}{2}+\cdots+\frac{1}{k}$$

These are called [harmonic numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_number).  Then your sum is $H_{100}-\frac{1}{2}H_{50}-1$.

If you're happy with an approximation, we know that $H_k\approx \ln k + \frac{1}{2k}+\gamma$, where $\gamma\approx  0.5772156$.  Hence your answer is approximately $\ln 100 + \gamma-0.5 \ln 50 -\frac{\gamma}{2}-1\approx 1.93776648$

You can get an exact answer on [Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%28H_100%29++-++%28H_50%2F2%29), but it isn't particularly nice.  The above approximation is correct to four decimal places.

Comment: How did you end up with $H_{100}-\frac{1}{2}H_{50}-1$?

Comment: @MyUsername112358, you are responding to a post from almost 4 years ago.  Write out the terms of $H_{50}$, divide each in half, and you will get terms with even denominators.  Subtract those from $H_{100}$ and you're almost there.

Comment: Thank you, I understand now. Is there something wrong with responsing to a post from 4 years ago?

Comment: It's not wrong, but it's more likely to be ignored.  Basically the only person who saw your response is me; lucky for you I'm still active on the site.

Comment: Yeah I know, but i stalked your account to see if you were active or not first haha

Answer (score -2):

You could probably use simple sequence addition then simplify afterwords,
For example $1+3+5......99$ is equivalent to $((99+1)/2)^2$ which is $2500$ so the denominator would be $2500$ then find the number of terms and add the numerator.